# firebase.storage().ref("image/").listAll() is not a function and undefined

Tags: node.js

package used is react-native firebase.

```
firebase.storage().ref("image/").listAll().then( function (result){
  result.items.forEach( function (all) {
    console.log("image reference" + all.toString())
  });
 }).catch((error)=> {
   console.log(error);
   alert(error)
 });
```

Comment: Please write only in English. Thx!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `firebase.storage().ref().child("image/").listAll()` ?

Comment: j"ai essayé cette ,ethode et ca ne marche pas . ca ,e renvoie une erreur du genre firebase.storage().ref().child("image/") n'est pas une fonction et indefinie

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you misspelled the image folder in firebase otherwise this code is working

```
function ListAnother(){
firebase.storage().ref("images/").listAll().then( function (result){
    result.items.forEach( function (all) {
      console.log("image reference" + all.toString())
    });
   }).catch((error)=> {
     console.log(error);
     alert(error)
   });
}
```